# Calculate mean for certain period of months

Tags: r

I have temperature data from 2010-2020.

I want to calculate  mean temperature of November 2010-April 2011 (one value of mean), and then November 2011-April 2012 (one value of mean), and then November 2012-April 2013 (one value of mean) and so on with same pattern until April 2020. How do I calculate them? Please help me kind people. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I assume no missing years, all years having at least a few dates within the months ranges and your data ordered by date. I did not include incomplete "winters" in your results.

**using `data.table` and `lubridate`**

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
  
df[, month := month(date)][, .SD[
  first(year(date)) != last(year(date)) & (month >= 11 | month <= 4), 
  .(period = paste(first(year(date)), last(year(date)), sep = "-"), mean = mean(value))
], rleid(month >= 11 | month <= 4)][, -1]
```

**results**

```
 1: 2010-2011  13.5
 2: 2011-2012  25.5
 3: 2012-2013  37.5
 4: 2013-2014  49.5
 5: 2014-2015  61.5
 6: 2015-2016  73.5
 7: 2016-2017  85.5
 8: 2017-2018  97.5
 9: 2018-2019 109.5
10: 2019-2020 121.5
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(ymd("2010-01-01"), ymd("2020-12-01"), "months"),
  value = 1:132
)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for response. I found this error while running the command:
Error in `:=`(month, month(date)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=")

Comment: Make sure you loaded data.table library and make your data.frame a data.table